# "If I let the video finish playing..."

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I have included a video in the slides that I prepared for a talk I have to give next week and my plan is to hit play at the beginning, then pause the video for one moment and finally let it reach its full length.

However, I am not quite sure how to describe verbally the former actions correctly. Is it fine if I say after the pause:

1. Now if I let the video finish playing,...
2. Now if I resume the video, ...

Comment: Why do you need "if" in either version?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's effectively a form of "proofreading" where the OP just wants us to indicate our preference for either of two perfectly valid ways for the speaker to indicate what he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say either:

1. Now I will let the video finish playing...

Or more conversationally and informally

2. Let's resume the video...

If you say "Now if I resume the video,..." it suggests an event you want to draw attention to following the restart. For example, *Now if I resume the video **you should see see the result of the experiment***.

Even then, a more direct way of expressing it would be: *Let's resume the video to see the result of the experiment.*

But you've only said that you're resuming the video, not that you want to draw attention to an event later in the video.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is exactly what I needed!